# Why is my Google Cloud Platform(GCP) console displaying nothing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-scheduler

[Google Cloud Platform console not displaying anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmi4A.png)

Comment: An ad blocker or antivirus can cause this problem. Open the browser debugger and look for errors on the Console and Network tabs.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to work even after deleting and clearing caches and cookies and also disabling the adBlocker. The only solution seems to be using a different browser(Edge). Thanks for your suggestion.